# netplan network accessibility check

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, netplan, network-monitoring

Is there any way to check connectivity in netplan to check real connection state (is Internet connection alive or not)? As an example, I have a connection through LAN router (default gateway) and fallback through LTE. Of course, link between Ubuntu server and LAN router always available, but, sometimes, LAN router can lose WAN. So, Ubuntu server have to use LTE while routers WAN down. Something like connectivity check in NM https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/networkmanager/snap-configuration/connectivity-check

Comment: You would need to write a script.

Comment: I am an absolute newbie in netplan. Can you provide some examples?

Comment: It is not a netplan thing. You would need to write a script maybe in bash to check connection status.

Comment: Can you provide some scripts examples?

Comment: Sorry no I do not do that stuff.